# web.config connection string for Oracle Data Provider for .NET

Tags: .net, oracle, web-config, odp.net, data-connections

Does anyone know the connection string for Oracle Data Provider for .NET for .NET 4.0 ?

I have tried entering the Data Connection properties as a connection string and looking on connectionstrings.com.  Neither seem to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/

Answer (score 2):

You may check [Oracle Data Provider for .NET / ODP.NET connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle-data-provider-for-net-odp-net/):

```
Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)(PORT=MyPort)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID)));
User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```